# Why is iptables not dropping packets?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, ip, tcp

I have the following rule in our iptables config file /etc/sysconfig/iptables

```
-A INPUT -s 84.23.99.97 -j DROP
```

And when I do iptables --list I get the following

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  84.23.99.97          anywhere


Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

However, if I do a tcpdump I can still see all these traffic from this ip, why?

```
tcpdump -ttttn tcp port 1234 | grep 84.23.99.97
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
2010-10-21 23:49:33.828011 IP 84.23.99.97.9061 > myip: Flags [S], seq 3522466008, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,eol], length 0
2010-10-21 23:49:33.832182 IP 84.23.99.97.64804 > myip: Flags [S], seq 1088176500, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,eol], length 0
....
```

Answer (score 5):

tcpdump [sees inbound traffic before it hits iptables](http://mydebian.blogdns.org/?p=85). In your example above this explains why you see inbound SYNs but not SYN/ACKs from your machine.

Comment: Whats a good way to know if the actual traffic is dropped then?

Comment: You can configure a `-j LOG` target that sends information about the matching (dropped) packets to the system log. Also, when you list the iptables rules with `iptables -L -v -n`, if you see non-zero counts next to your DROP rule, then you know that packets were matched (and hence DROPed) by that rule.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your rules.  Maybe you did, but didn't mention it?  If not try this:
% sudo /sbin/service iptables save

This exports the rules currently used and starts the firewall.  Regardless of what you have in /etc/sysconfig/iptables this will tell you what the firewall is actually using.